# Find the best combination of numbers to minimize waste

Tags: excel, vba

I am creating a program that will minimize the amount of excess rail I waste on Solar jobs. The concept is I have X number of Solar Panels and I can use either 123" or 163.5" rail to hold it, or I can cut either rail in half and splice them together. I want to create a VBA that will try all combinations of rail and find the minimum amount of leftover rail.

I have created a loop that increments one rail at a time until it finds the minimum leftover rail, but I'm having trouble incrementing both rails. It would need to increase one rail by .5, check, increment the other, check, repeat until it's > width.

Comment: This is not an appropriate question for StackOverflow.  You may intend to implement your solution using Excel VBA but before you can think about code you need an algorithm.  I would try Stack Exchange: Computational Science: Algorithms or search for "resource optimisation".

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it seeks an algorithm. I suspect Computation Science: Algorithms would be an appropriate Stack Exchange site but I do not know how to propose migration to that site.

Comment: I would have been tempted to put it in [Code Golf](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/), seems like a fun one.

Comment: I've never heard of these places before, I'll have to check them out. I basically used the same process as a what-if analysis. Just incrementing every possible combination until it finds the smallest number. It ended up working pretty well.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, after creating an insanely complex series of if/then and loops i've figured it out. It's not simple, but it works.